# Macros in C++ breaks with postfix increments

Tags: c++, macros

I need a working MAX macros (without(!) declaring main function) which assign 'r' the maximum of numbers 'a' and 'b'. This code breaks in compilation. How can it be fixed?

```
#define MAX(x, y, r) ((x) > (y) ? (r = x) : (r = y))

int x = 10;
int y = 20;
int r;

MAX(x, y, r);
```

Thanks for watching!

UPD: Some revision to clear the full task:

```
#import <iostream>
#define MAX(x, y, r) ((x) > (y) ? (r = x) : (r = y))

int x = 1;
int y = 1;
int r = 1;

int main()
{
    MAX(x++, y, r);
    std::cout << r;
    return 0;
}
```

The result of this code is 1, and need to be 2. So I need another logic in my macros to consider all postfix increments

Comment: 1) why 2) what is compilation error

Comment: Are you doing this outside of a function scope? That won't work, you can't put arbitrary expressions there.

Comment: Your update is a prime example of why you shouldn't use macros, as any code you pass to them may be executed multiple times. Do you absolutely need a macro for this?

Comment: Yes, I need working macros.

Comment: Okay, and you want `x++` to be executed only once, but the value considered in the macro to be that of the variable used in the expression *after* the expression has been executed?

Comment: Not fully understand question. The point is I only need 'magic' 2nd line with macros which consider all postfix increments with numbers 'x' and 'y', including the fact that number 'r' will also be define as some number like in example (UPD version).

Comment: If you want that, you'd need to pass the name of the variables alongside an expression to evaluate, because the preprocessor can't extract the name of the variable from an expression used on it.

Comment: Why do you *need* macros? There are *very rarely* actual requirements on *code* used to do something. In 99.9% of cases, requirements are on the *results* of a process, not on the *code* used to do it. Why is e.g. an inline function not usable? IOW, this smells of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/201677).

Comment: It's using in online test to graduate, I know it's weird but I need to do it only that way.

Comment: You need to ensure that the macro arguments are evaluated only once. Hint: use a lambda.

Comment: kirbrown: Also, please do not change your question to a *different* question once people have provided answers to the original question. Doing so invalidates the answers, which were contributed in good faith. There is no cost for asking a new question.

Comment: "The result of this code is 1, and need to be 2." I'm sorry but with `x++` it doesn't make sense. Logically it should be 1 with `x++` and 2 with `++x`. Do you need `x++` and `++x` to behave in the same way?

Comment: The story is simple: I'm trying to pass some online course and I have the task about all of that staff, It's hard to say what the machine that compiles code and throw into it some testing numbers do with them, I hardly understand what it's want from me. Input already have the main() function functionality, so all starts working in my machine after I got the answer given by @SingerOfTheFall. All is good, but main problem will be my problem, because I can't understand how to say about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use this macro outside of a function, because it's an arbitrary expression, that's why you're getting an error.

Just move the invocation of the macro into function scope and it will work:

```
#define MAX(x, y, r) ((x) > (y) ? (r = x) : (r = y))

int x = 10;
int y = 20;
int r;

int main()
{
    MAX(x, y, r);
}
```

Using macros in this case is, however, unnecessary (unless this is just an exercise to learn macro usage); making `max` a function (or, better yet, using `std::max`) would be a better and less error-prone way.

Comment: This technically works, but I don't think advocating macros for this use is a good idea.

Comment: And using `r = std::max(x, y)` would be even better than rolling out your own.

Comment: @Angew, I think the OP is just learning this, so he will not use `std::max` anyway, but I've added that to the answer, thanks.

Comment: How does this solve the post-increment problem? It still evaluates twice whichever argument turns out to be the max.

Comment: @rici, the op hadn't updated his question at the time I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you can't put arbitrary expressions at file-scope. I have a couple of suggestions:

- Don't use global variables unless you really, really have to. They'll just cause you pain.
- Don't use macros unless you really, really have to. They'll just cause you pain.

Here's what I'd do:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    int r = std::max(x, y);
    //pass x, y and r as arguments to functions rather than using globals
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I now about the rules, but I have specific task witch needs to be done with macros.

Comment: @kirbrown Well you could just do `#define MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))` then `int r = MAX(x,y)`, but I really wouldn't advise it.